# How to write in a specific cell in a CSV file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, row, multiple-columns

I have an asignment in which I need to imput random grades of different students in a csv file using Python 3, and get the average of each student(the average thing and how to get the random grades, I know how to do it), the thing is that I don't know how to write the grades on those specific columns and rows(highlighted ones).

Highlighted area is the space in which I need to write random grades:
[image: image of grades file]

Is there anyway that this can be done? I'm fairly new to programming and Python 3, and as far as I've read, specifics cells can't be changed using normal means.

Comment: read all data into memory, add values in memory, write all data back to file.

Comment: Files with variable length records like CSV files cannot easily and efficiently be updated randomly. For that reason they are usually read entirely into memory, updated, and then the updated contents is used to completely rewrite the file.

Answer (score 0):

`csv` module doesn't have functions to modify specific cells.

You can read rows from original file, append grades and write modified rows to new file:

```py
import random
import csv

inputFile = open('grades.csv', 'r')
outputFile = open('grades_out.csv', 'w')
reader = csv.reader(inputFile)
writer = csv.writer(outputFile)
for row in reader:
    grades = row.copy()
    for i in range(5):
        grades.append(random.randint(1, 5))
    writer.writerow(grades)
inputFile.close()
outputFile.close()
```

Then you can delete original file and rename new file (it is not good to read the whole original file to a variable, close it, open it again in writing mode and then write data, because it can be big).